# Удаление динамического листа Pascal

Tags: pascal

Всем привет, не могу понять в чем дело, почему выводит ошибку.

Есть цикличный динамичный лист.
элемент[значение, ссылка]

Последний указывает на начало цикла, а не nil.

Пытаюсь удалить, но вываливает "инвалид поинтер 204".
Сидел, смотрел - удаление исполняется почему-то 2 раза, далее выкидывает ошибку.

Функции прокомментированы, думаю будет ясно.

Вот [ИСХОДНИК](http://paste.org.ru/?12t28z).

Вот сама функция удаления:

```
...

{DELETE ALL ELEMENTS OF LIST}
procedure DeleteList;
  var p: TPoint;
  begin
    repeat
      begin
        if BeginList^.Next = BeginList then
          begin
            dispose(BeginList);
            BeginList := nil;
            break;
          end
        else
          begin
            p := BeginList;
            BeginList := BeginList^.Next;
            dispose(p);
          end;
      end;
    until BeginList = nil
  end;

  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам код (по ссылке) не смотрел, но думаю этого и не надо (*не смотря даже на то, что с памятью в паскале работал 10 лет назад*).

Пара вопросов, ответы на которые помогут вам найти вашу ошибку.

**Первый вопрос:**

```
if BeginList^.Next = BeginList then
```

Вы где-то сохраняете BeginList? Сомневаюсь, т.к. смотрим ниже и видим:

```
BeginList := BeginList^.Next;
```

**По первой строчке еще пару вопросов**. Что эта строчка означает дословно? Вы где-то обновляете BeginList^.Next? Или по вашему она сама должна обновляться?

**Третий вопрос** Что происходит с ссылкой, если удалить объект, на который она ссылается?

Этих вопросов уже в принципе достаточно. Смотрите:

1. BeginList := BeginList^.Next - вы изменили BeginList, и вместе с нею изменился BeginList^.Next. Если они не равны изначально и вы нигде не меняете ссылку Next у объектов, то условие BeginList^.Next = BeginList не имеет смысла, т.к. всегда ложно.
2. if BeginList^.Next = BeginList then - эта строчка как раз и говорит - если текущий объект ссылается сам на себя, что в вашем случае не правильно, т.к. уже написал почему.
3. Вы удалили объект (вызвали dispose). Что стало с ссылкой? Она по прежнему ссылается на участок памяти, но по этому адресу не существует никаких объектов. По хорошему при удалении объекта следовало бы делать Next = nil для всех объектов, у которых Next ссылался на удаленный объект.
4. А следовательно проблема у вас в следующем - вы удалили первую ссылку. Прошлись по всем, а затем опять пытаетесь удалить первую ссылку. Ведь Next все еще ссылается на данный участок памяти. А поскольку вы никаких других действий не выполняли, то BeginList^.Next = BeginList будет почти всегда ложно (когда будет истина я уже писал).

В итоге получаем:

1. Вам надо знать когда остановиться. Можно сохранить текущее значение, передвинуться вперед и начать удаление всех элементов. Тогда ваш код должен работать (если вы, конечно, поменяете первую проверку на наше сохраненное значение)
2. Можно обойтись и без сохранений: находимся на текущем элементе. Удаляем следующий (!). Но перед удалением, меняем текущую ссылку NEXT на ссылку NEXT удаляемого элемента. При данном подходе ваше первоначальное условие сработает как и ожидается, т.к. удалив предпоследний элемент мы будем ссылаться сами на себя.

[@Shrek](/users/4597/shrek), списки могут быть и однонаправленными, ими, например, можно реализовать очередь или стек. В циклических списках ссылка на прошлый элемент тоже не шибко-то и нужна, т.к. пройдя вперед я все равно получу ее. Единственное - с нею удобства больше.

Comment: Вот, расписывать я не стал, но идея та же :)

Да можно и в одну сторону, но когда можешь ползать вперед и назад - это удобнее.

Comment: Блин, ребята, туплю жестко. С ошибкой BeginList, что он указывал сам на себя постоянно увидел еще со шреком, стало грустно :) Сейчас вроде как исправил, по теории должно сработать, но нет.

var p, List: TPoint;
  begin
    List := BeginList;
    repeat
      begin
writeln('iteration');
        if List^.Next = BeginList then
          begin
            dispose(BeginList);
            BeginList := nil;
            break;
          end
        else
          begin
            p := List;
            List := p^.Next;
            dispose(p);
          end;
      end;
    until BeginList = nil
  end

Comment: Ну так опять же... Попробуйте повторить то, что должен сделать компилятор на бумаге, если в голове не можете выполнить эти действия...

Первым шагом вы устанавливаете ссылку на текущий элемент. Затем удаляете его и все последующие. На последнем шаге вы пытаетесь удалить уже удаленный элемент.

Я же писал - установили ссылку - сдвинулись вперед и только потом удаляете. Ну либо вместо последнего удаления просто выход из процедуры.

И еще - if List^.Next = BeginList then - происходит удаление только следующего элемента. А текущий так и остается висеть в памяти - типичная утечка.

Comment: "Ну либо вместо последнего удаления просто выход из процедуры." - т.е. удаляете текущий элемент (который List, а не BeginList) и выходите, иначе - утечка о которой писал выше.

И еще - как-то с детства привык при уничтожении элементов обнулять ссылки. Может и не критично, но мне так проще.

А вам проще было бы - реализовать процедуру удаления по одному элементу, процедуру перемещения на следующий элемент и т.д. Тогда работали бы уже именно со списком и его элементами, а не с памятью - так сказать первый шаг на пути к ООП.

Comment: Хе-хе... А вы в курсе, что у вас ругается не на удаление элемента, а на PushAfter? Это во-первых, а во-вторых - на GetCount. А все почему?

    repeat
        count := count + 1;
        List := List^.Next;
    until(List = BeginList);

Это из GetCount. Если список не пуст - все ОК, а что если он пуст? List := List^.Next; сразу же вылетит с ошибкой...

    begin
        p^.Value := value;
        p^.Next := BeginList;
        ...
    end

Это уже из PushAfter. Что такое p? Компилятор не знает, а вы пытаетесь это "что-то" разыменовать...

Ну и плюс косяки с удалением не забудьте исправить.

Comment: В общем [здесь](http://paste.org.ru/?o5s8km) привел ваш код с моими баг-фиксами. Оформлением не занимался, внес только те изменения, про которые вам говорил.

Работу проверял [здесь](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_pascal_online.php)

Если честно - в таком виде сдавать очень даже опасно, лучше переписать в нормальном виде. Ваш пример - только ради учебы, чтобы понять как работать с памятью, но ни как не готовая лаба.

Comment: Давно не заходил сюда и не помню уже почему вопрос этот задавал, спасибо за детальное разъяснение. Столько лет прошло уже. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Последний указывает на начала цикла, а не nil.

А вот это то и неправильно. Последний должен идти в null это по правилам.
Почитай еще раз про динамические массивы на паскале.

Дело в том что так никто не делает. т.к. появляются лишние действия при удалении/добавлении первого/последнего элементов. это не есть хорошо.

Лучше пересмотреть эту структуру.

А не кажется что изначально нужно задать начальное значение для next.

```
if BeginList^.Next = BeginList then
```

А не просто взять и сделать условие?

а потом узнать следующее значение next и только потом удалить элемент, далее повторить операцию до момента пока next!=null а в вашем случае выползет ошибка, т.к. первый элемент ты удалишь, и последнему некуда ссылаться он никогда не найдет тот самый первый элемент.

И из этого вывод и показ ошибки.

Зы, глянул код - это жесть.

У динамического списка должно быть минимум 3 значения

1. Это само значение(будь то переменная, массив, строка и т.д.)
2. ссылка на предыдущий элемент
3. ссылка на следующий элемент

В коде есть только ссылка на следующий элемент списка и значение.

А иначе это какой-то странный список, ну по крайней мере для меня, уж если делать то правильно.

Comment: Я знаю, так должен закончится обычный список.

А этот, как я указал - "цикличный", то есть у него конец указывает на начало.

Comment: UPDATE #2:

Еще такой вопрос, если уж проблема в последнем элементе, почему ошибка вылетает после 2го прохождения по циклу? Элементов то я добавил 6 штук.

Comment: А ты возьми ручку/карандаш.
И на листке бумаги пошагово добавь все элементы, а потом по твоему коду попробуй их по удалять, ну или воспользуйся встроенным пошаговым выполнением в паскале. Он тебе все покажет и не забудь вывод переменных сделать, увидишь в чем косяк.

ps

>почему ошибка вылетает после 2го прохождения по циклу?

скорее всего не после второго прохождения, а после 2 итерации, прохождение это значит пройти полностью по циклу.

Comment: Извиняюсь, имел ввиду итерацию. Сейчас проверяю, отпишусь сразу.