# Почему функция не валидирует ссылки с русским текстом?

Tags: php

```
return (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false) ? true : false;
```

Если в качестве `$url` дать ссылку:

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198948/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-pascal
```

Функция вернет false.

В документации сказано:

> Обратите внимание, что функция
>   работает только с ASCII-ссылками

В это и причина, если русский текст?

Comment: попробуй закодировать ссылку через urlencode, а потом прогнать через filter_var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо как-то так делать, только не так страшно:

```
$url = urlencode('http://hashcode.ru/questions/198948/удаление-динамического-листа-pascal');
$url = str_replace(array('%3A', '%2F'), array(':', '/'), $url);
print '<pre>'; var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

ну и без протокола не работает.

Answer (score 0):

[А вот если прочитать мануал до конца](http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.validate.php), то:

> Обратите внимание, что функция работает только с ASCII-ссылками, таким образом, интернациональные доменные имена (содержащие не-ASCII символы) не пройдут проверку.

Можно попробовать валидировать [регулярными выражениями](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123845/).